# Stability of equilibrium point in matrix case (arbitrary dimension)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Consider a linear first order differential equation: $$y'=\alpha\bigg(1-\frac{y}{K}\bigg)y$$ where $y, K, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. We know the solution for $y'=0$ is at $y=0$ and $y=K$.

Through **phase-line plot** technique, we know the $y=K$ is asymptotically stable and $y=0$ is unstable.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_line_(mathematics)

Suppose now we consider the above in the matrix case:

$$\dot{R} = AR$$ where $A,R\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, then how to decide the equilibrium point is stable or not?

Comment: Use the phase-plane technique.

Comment: @JackyChong Thanks. So for $n=2$ use phase plane, $n\geq 3$ use phase space. I will try this.

Comment: Just study the eigenvalues.